# Unable to insert a tuple or array into an sql table -- variable is ambigious

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I'm trying to insert a tuple or list to an sql table such that simple doesn't compile:

```
--1

newId <- execute cn "insert into mytable (var1, var2, ,) values (?, ?)" ["var1", "var2"]


--2
newId <- execute cn "insert into mytable (var1, var2, ,) values (?, ?)" ("var1", "var2")
```

The errors are:

```
No instance for (ToField t0) arising from a use of ‘execute’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance ToField Value
        -- Defined in ‘Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField’
      instance ToField a => ToField (Maybe a)
        -- Defined in ‘Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField’
      instance ToField Int16
        -- Defined in ‘Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToField’
      ...plus 42 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      newId <- execute
```

Comment: Are you using `OverloadedStrings`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, yes, and?

Comment: then just use `("var1" :: Text)` ....

Comment: So the list has a type of `IsString s => [s]`, not `[String]`, and GHC doesn't know how to choose a type which satisfied both `IsString` and `ToField`. Give a type signature to the literal: `["var1", "var2"] :: [String]`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I think `String` is not int [`ToField`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.1.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-ToField.html#t:ToField)

Comment: if you look at the [Type inference part of the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.1.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html) the problem and the solution is mentioned

Comment: right from there: "The same kind of problem can arise with string literals if you have the OverloadedStrings language extension enabled. Again, just use an explicit type signature if this happens."

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, `Couldn't match expected type ‘[String]’ with actual type ‘IO Int64’` -- execute returns Int64.

Comment: @aYT you've got your parentheses wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when you have [`OverloadedStrings`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings) turned on. With the extension, string literals have a type of [`IsString s => s`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) (not `String`).
GHC is struggling to choose an instance of `ToField s` because it doesn't know what `s` is.

The same thing happens when you say `show . read`: there's nothing directing GHC to choose a particular instance of `Show` or `Read`.

The fix is simple: give a type signature to the literal.

```
execute sqlSnippet (["var1", "var2"] :: [Text])  -- or [String] if you really want
```

The [`postgresql-simple` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.1.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#g:4) explains this in detail.